# Mathematical notation of an one hot vectors in ML

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, machine-learning, scientific-notation

I have a vector a vector of length $n$and can only contain values $\{A,B,C\}$. I'm representing this mathematically as:
$$\mathbf{x} \in \{A,B,C\}^{1\times n}$$
**Question 1:** Am I properly mathematically representing what I am saying in words?

I first map this vector to numerical values with the following mapping function: $f: \{A,B,C\} \rightarrow \{2,4,8\} $

**Question 2:** I've seen mapping functions written this way but is there a simpler, more intuitive way to do it?

Then, I take $f(\mathbf{x})$ and convert into a one-hot vector format such that:
$$OneHot(f(x)) \in \mathbb{R}^{v\times n}$$
where $v$ is the size of the vocabulary of $\mathbf{x}$. In this case, $v=3$.

**Question 3:** How can I mathematically represent one hot vector notation? I do see some option in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/125612/133742). Is there a more intuitive way to represent it? The representation in the post isn't immediately obvious for a non pure math person.

Comment: When we use the notation $f:U \to V$, both $U$ and $V$ should be sets. But $(A,B,C)$ is not a set, it’s an ordered triple. So, I’d say the notation $f:(A,B,C) \to (2,4,8)$ is not correct.

Comment: Good point, I've updated it now. @littleO

Comment: Perhaps you could say: Let $\text{OneHot}(x)$ be the $3 \times 100$ matrix whose $i$th column (for $i =1,\ldots,100$) is either $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$  (if $x_i = A$) or $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (if $x_i = B$) or $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ (if $x_i = C$).

Comment: But what if $v$ is some larger value, i.e. $x$ has a larger vocabulary, e.g. $v=10$? @littleO